# Error creating vaadin design project using eclipse: Unhandled event loop exception java.lang.NullPointerException at com.vaadin.designer.eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin

I want to create a vaadin project using the vaadin design. But I can't get pass **creating a new project** even though I have vaadin designer plugins installed as I get the error shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.